# mysql installation fails on ubuntu 18.10

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I'm trying to setup my minipc that came with ubuntu 10.10. I'm following the LAMP installation instructions on Digital Ocean, but the mySql installation fails with the following message:

```
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I've tried the suggestion and I get the same results. I've also tried rebooting the system and that didn't help.

The following is the terminal output from the installation attempt.

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
[sudo] password for minipc: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libaio1 libevent-core-2.1-6 libhtml-template-perl mysql-client-5.7
  mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-common mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7
Suggested packages:
  libipc-sharedcache-perl mailx tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libaio1 libevent-core-2.1-6 libhtml-template-perl mysql-client-5.7
  mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-5.7
  mysql-server-core-5.7
0 upgraded, 9 newly installed, 0 to remove and 313 not upgraded.
Need to get 20.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 159 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Ign:1 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 mysql-common all 5.8+1.0.4
Err:2 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 libaio1 amd64 0.3.111-1
  Temporary failure resolving 'cn.archive.ubuntu.com'
Ign:3 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/main amd64 mysql-client-core-5.7 amd64 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.10.2
Ign:4 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/main amd64 mysql-client-5.7 amd64 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.10.2
Ign:5 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/main amd64 mysql-server-core-5.7 amd64 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.10.2
Err:6 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 libevent-core-2.1-6 amd64 2.1.8-stable-4build1
  Temporary failure resolving 'cn.archive.ubuntu.com'
Ign:7 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/main amd64 mysql-server-5.7 amd64 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.10.2
Ign:8 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 libhtml-template-perl all 2.97-1
Ign:9 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/main amd64 mysql-server all 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.10.2
Err:1 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 mysql-common all 5.8+1.0.4
  Temporary failure resolving 'cn.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:8 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 libhtml-template-perl all 2.97-1
  Temporary failure resolving 'cn.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/main amd64 mysql-client-core-5.7 amd64 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.10.2
  Temporary failure resolving 'cn.archive.ubuntu.com'
Ign:9 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/main amd64 mysql-server all 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.10.2
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/main amd64 mysql-client-5.7 amd64 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.10.2
  Temporary failure resolving 'cn.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/main amd64 mysql-server-core-5.7 amd64 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.10.2
  Temporary failure resolving 'cn.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/main amd64 mysql-server-5.7 amd64 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.10.2
  Temporary failure resolving 'cn.archive.ubuntu.com'
Ign:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/main amd64 mysql-server all 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.10.2
Err:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/main amd64 mysql-server all 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.10.2
  Temporary failure resolving 'cn.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-defaults/mysql-common_5.8+1.0.4_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'cn.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/liba/libaio/libaio1_0.3.111-1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'cn.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.7/mysql-client-core-5.7_5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.10.2_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'cn.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.7/mysql-client-5.7_5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.10.2_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'cn.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.7/mysql-server-core-5.7_5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.10.2_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'cn.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libe/libevent/libevent-core-2.1-6_2.1.8-stable-4build1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'cn.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.7/mysql-server-5.7_5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.10.2_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'cn.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libh/libhtml-template-perl/libhtml-template-perl_2.97-1_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'cn.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.7/mysql-server_5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.10.2_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'cn.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Maybe a dns error have you tried checking /etc/resolve.conf

Comment: As @KevinRockwell points out, the error is "Temporary failure resolving 'cn.archive.ubuntu.com' " etc. From a browser, try to go to *cn.archive.ubuntu.com* - you should see the "Index of / ", i.e. root.